# How to index a table automatically and loop it in ipairs while keeping all data?

Tags: loops, lua, indexing, lua-table

Table:

```
localization_strings = {
    string_1 = "Text Here",
    string_2 = "Some More Text Here",
    string_3 = "More Text"
}
```

This is obviously not the whole table, but just a small sample. The real table is over 500+ lines. The reason I don't just redo the table is because other functions reference it and I don't have access to those files to fix them, so I have to find a work around. Also, because it would quite tedious work and can cause problems with other codes.

I have made 2 attempts at solving this problem, but I can only get one of the values I want (incorrect terminology, I think) and I need both as 1 is display text and 1 is data for a function call.

Attempts:

```
-- Attempt #1
-- Gives me the string_#'s but not the "Text"...which I need, as I want to display the text via another function
LocalizationUnorderedOpts = {}
LocalizationOpts = {}
for n,unordered_names in pairs(localization_strings) do
    if (unordered_names) then
        table.insert( LocalizationUnorderedOpts, n)
    end
end
io.write(tostring(LocalizationUnorderedOpts) .. "\n")
table.sort(LocalizationUnorderedOpts)

for i,n in ipairs(LocalizationUnorderedOpts) do 
    if (n) then
        io.write(tostring(i))
        table.insert( LocalizationOpts, { text = tostring(LocalizationUnorderedOpts[i]), callback = function_pointer_does_not_matter, data = i } )
    end
end

-- Attempt #2
-- Gives me the "Text" but not the string_#'s...which I need to as data to the callback to another function (via function pointer)
LocalizationUnorderedOpts = {}
LocalizationOpts = {}
for n,unordered_names in pairs(localization_strings) do
    if (unordered_names) then
        table.insert( LocalizationUnorderedOpts, localization_strings[n])
    end
end
io.write(tostring(LocalizationUnorderedOpts) .. "\n")
table.sort(LocalizationUnorderedOpts)

for i,n in ipairs(LocalizationUnorderedOpts) do 
    if (n) then
        io.write(tostring(i))
        table.insert( LocalizationOpts, { text = tostring(LocalizationUnorderedOpts[i]), callback = function_pointer_does_not_matter, data = i } )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you need to sort the non-array table. Your first attempt has done most of the work: build another table, which has the values the same as the keys in the original table.

What's left is how to get the original values like  `"Text Here"`, for that you need to index the original table:

```
for k, v in ipairs(LocalizationUnorderedOpts) do
    print(v)                       --original key
    print(localization_strings[v]) --original value
end
```

Comment: That gives me a nil value when it tries to find the key. Unless I did something wrong...not sure what. I forgot to mention that the final table/loop to table insert, needs to follow the format of table.insert( finalTableName, {text = "Texts here", callback - func_pointer, data = key}). "Texts here" will be the table being iterated through, if I am not mistaken on my terminology, while key will be the data I need (AKA string_#)

Comment: Ok, well it works now, wonder what I did wrong before. The only problem now is the code is a little bit messy but I don't know if it's possible to optimize it or clean it up more? Also, how does sort work? The list is in order, but some stuff appears out of order based on what the table looks like, but most of it is in the correct order. Any reason why? Does table.sort do it by alphabetization?